# Wrong number of arguments (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

```
class Testdeck
    attr_accessor :cards

    def initialize
        @cards = []
        counter = 0
        ['H','C', 'S', 'D'].product['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','K','Q','A'].each do |arr|
            @cards << Card.new(arr[0], arr[1])
        end
    end
end

zen = Testdeck.new
puts zen.cards.pop
```

I have spent the last hour trying to fix this error. The error I get is:

```
wrong number of arugments (Argument Error)
```

Comment: Could you be so kind and attach FULL error message with backtrace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the parens in the `product` method call; try this:

```
def initialize
    @cards = []
    counter = 0
    ['H','C', 'S', 'D'].product(['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','K','Q','A']).each do |arr|
        @cards << Card.new(arr[0], arr[1])
    end
end
```

The problem is that you're actually accessing the `[]` method on `product` which will result on calling `product` without arguments and then slicing the result.

```
['H','C', 'S', 'D'].product # == [["H"], ["C"], ["S"], ["D"]]
```

Since you can't pass 13 arguments to `[]` (which is the size of your second array), that's why you got `wrong number of arguments (13 for 1..2)`.

Adding the parens will make your second array the argument of `product` and *then* will call `each` on the result, so:

```
['H','C', 'S', 'D'].product[1, 2] # == [["C"], ["S"]] 

['H','C', 'S', 'D'].product [1, 2] == ['H','C', 'S', 'D'].product([1, 2]) # == [["H", 1], ["H", 2], ["C", 1], ["C", 2], ["S", 1], ["S", 2], ["D", 1], ["D", 2]]
                           ^ important separation here
```

As you can see, you can drop the `()` and use a space, but in your case, you can't chain the `each` later on, that's why you'll have to add them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write as below :

```
(['H','C', 'S', 'D'].product ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','K','Q','A']).each do |arr|
```

Answer (score 0):

See @NicoSantangelo answer it is the correct one, here is a version using `map` to initialize the `@cards` instance variable

```
suites = ['H', 'C', 'S', 'D']
values = ('2'..'10').to_a + ['J', 'K', 'Q', 'A']

@cards = suites.product(values).map do |parts|
  Card.new(parts[0], parts[1])
end
```